# gooroutine is have a priority or not？

Tags: go

Golang fish，Seeking explanation.

Goroutine is have a priority or not？

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
  var total int
  for _, v := range a {
    total += v
  }
  c <- total
}

func main() {
  a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}
  c := make(chan int)
  go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
  go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)

  // x, y := <-c, <-c
  x := <-c
  y := <-c
  fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

why the x is -5 y is 17，is not the first goroutine blocked?
if

```
go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
x := <-c
go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
y := <-c
```

this order is right. why。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the output should be either `-5 17 12` or `17 -5 12`. Both goroutines are running concurrently (at the same time). The result of whichever goroutine finishes first will be stored in the variable `x`. The result of the other goroutine is stored in `y`. In order to better see that the goroutines are running concurrently, you can put a random timer inside the function `sum()`. This way, you should see the output change between different runs, because one goroutine randomly takes longer than the other:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
)

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1000000)))   // wait for up to 1ms
    total := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        total += v
    }
    c <- total
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}
    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)

    x := <-c
    y := <-c
    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

In your second example, you are starting the first goroutine. Then you read from the channel `c`, which is a blocking operation (meaning it will wait until there's a result => the first goroutine is done). The output here is deterministic and will always be `17 -5 12`.

Comment: thanks,i want to know goroutine is  parallel or concurrency？

Comment: It depends on how `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` is set. Here's a good explanation: https://www.goinggo.net/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html